# high charts legend labels symbols issue can't get the rectangle

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to change high charts legend labels symbols to rectangle. I tried some references but i'm getting square on top of default symbol. What I need is this [Legend labels with just rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUutS.png)

Comment: What are have you tried and what is the result? Some code snippets would help.

Comment: Thanks nathan for reply. i tried this http://jsfiddle.net/anchika/gb32bx2j/1/. its showing square and default symbol. i also tried https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/. but none of them giving me just a rectangle

Answer (score 0):

You had almost the solution. You need to create your own symbol using the SVG renderer like that:

```
// Define a custom symbol path
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.rectangle = function (x, y, w, h) {
    return ['M', x, y, 'L', x + w*2, y, 'L', x+w*2, y + h,'L', x, y + h, 'z'];
};
if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross;
}
```

You can learn more about [SVG Paths here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Tutoriel/Paths)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujnoqwmb/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Core972. i tried that but it's not working. may be because i'm using  Highcharts.stockChart. the above code will it works for highcharts and highStocks?

Comment: @sai, I updated the fiddle with highstock and the symbol works too.

Comment: for me its not showing any change in the fiddle. can you send it again please

Comment: @sai, look this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jpfv9sm2/) I added the symbol to the main serie too.

Comment: Thanks Core972. but some how it's not working for me. will that works for highstocks?

Comment: @sai, the fiddle in my previous comment use highstocks so I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: @sai, it looks that this solution does not work with Highstock, but you can easily use the features from Highstock in basic chart: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5rkfwsv6/

Comment: Hi Core972. I'm trying to show dates on x-axis. but they are showing one day off. can you help me. this is the question i have created. highcharts x-axis date issue